# Using Hackage libraries

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, hackage

I am just starting out with Haskell .I am using stack to build my applcation.
I am trying to use this library from hackage .
http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pkcs10-0.2.0.0/docs/Data-X509-PKCS10.html

I am not able to figure out how to include this in the code .
I tried adding X509 and PKCS10 ,PKCS to my cabal file under build depends ,but that doesnt work .
Why do I do to use the functions in this library.
Any links to a tutorial for this would be great ,I tried looking but could not find any.

Comment: In my professional opinion, screw stack.  Use cabal (and cabal sandbox if there's dependency trouble) instead.  `cabal install pkcs10`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package name in this case is `pkcs10`. Add it to your .cabal file into `build-depends` field. Stack should figure out the rest.

Comment: This worked thanks . I was not aware that the case of the letters could result in a problem .